# How can I get "Open PowerShell Here" in my context menu?

Tags: windows-vista, powershell, context-menu

In XP I was used to having the "Open Command Window Here" option in my context menu for folders.  In Vista, it's hidden by default, but I know that I can hold shift when right clicking to see that option.

What I want to know is, how can I get the same functionality, except for PowerShell instead of cmd.exe?

Even better would be to get it to always be there without having to shift+right click.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Answered at Stackoverflow: [How to start PowerShell from Windows Explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183901/how-to-start-powershell-from-windows-explorer)

Comment: Nice, although it chokes when you try to use a path that has any single quotes in it.